# Git merge-base produces no result on build server cloned repo

Tags: git, merge-base

I have the following git branch scenario:

```
     F0---F1---Fn (feature: checked out)
    /
---D0---          (dev)
```

When I issue the command `git merge-base dev HEAD` on my local repository it returns the commit SHA for D0.

On our build server, which is a GitLab Runner for GitLab pipelines CI/CD, it clones the repository when a build is triggered. For some reason that I cannot figure out the same command on the server returns nothing.

Any idea what the issue is or what I am missing?

Comment: Does the CI runner maybe do a shallow clone with limited history (for performance reasons), and the merge base is not part of it?

Comment: Yes, it does perform shallow cloning and the clone depth is configurable. Good point, I can try increasing.

Answer (score 2):

Increasing the fetch depth was the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with fetch depth.
You just need to add the '**GIT_DEPTH**' variable to the Gitlab job in which you are executing the git command.

for example,

```
deploy_release:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    GIT_DEPTH: 1000 // (Whatever the suitable value for you)
  script:
```